# How do I count objects that have an id below the current id in django

Tags: python, sql, django

```
class Shoe(models.Model):
     title = models.Charfield(max_length=120)
```

The query i am using is:

```
old_shoes = Shoe.objects.all().count()
```

I want to get shoes with id's below the current id, would something like this work

```
old_shoes = Shoe.objects.all(id>shoe.id).count()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `filter`, because `all` will return all objects for the model Shoe.

Also, you need to use `__lt` instead of `<` to filter the QuerySet. [See the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#lte)

So use `old_shoes = Shoe.objects.filter(id__lt = shoe.id).count()`

Answer (score 2):

In order to filter `Shoe`s with an `id` lower than the given id, you use the [**`__lt`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#lt):

```
old_shoes = Shoe.objects.filter(id__lt=shoe.id).count()
```